# Access parent project SWIFT_FLAGS/SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS from pod framework

Tags: cocoapods

I know it's not very right way to do things but whatever.

I have this code in my framework, and I can set up `current` from a project. But I prefer for it to be done without direct set up.

```
public extension Environment {
    static var current: Environment = {
        #if DEBUG
            return .debug
        #elseif CIT
            return .cit
        #elseif STAGING
            return .staging
        #elseif PRODUCTION
            return .production
        #elseif RELEASE
            return .release
        #else
            return .debug
        #endif
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a post_install hook that I came up using help from other similar posts.

Fill `SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS` in the project 
and add code below to the Podfile.

Xcode 10.

```
post_install do |installer|

  require 'xcodeproj'
  project_path = 'Test.xcodeproj' # path to your xcode project
  project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)

  project.targets.each do |projectTarget|
    if projectTarget.name == 'Test' # name of the target in your main project containing the custom flags
      installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |podConfig|
        projectTarget.build_configurations.each do |projectConfig|
          if projectConfig.name == podConfig.name
            podConfig.build_settings["SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS"] ||= [projectConfig.build_settings["SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS"]]
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```